# Embedding QCustomPlot In ScrollArea

Tags: qt, qt5, qcustomplot

I'm fairly new to qcustomplot and qt (switching from pyqt+matplotlib for performance upgrade / learning). I've been looking into the tutorial for qcustomplot but all revolves around drawing a UI with a Qwidget being promoted to QCustomPlot, which is great but Im guessing would require manual drawing if I want more than one Qcustomplot / subplots with fixed / view-able size. So far, I've been trying to create a customplot with multiple axis to see if the axis changes size within the scrollarea, but so far no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

The header files

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The cpp follows:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "qcustomplot.h"
#include <QWidget>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget plotWidget;
    QVBoxLayout layout;
    QCustomPlot customPlot;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        customPlot.plotLayout()->insertRow(i);
        QCPAxisRect *ar = new QCPAxisRect(&customPlot);
        customPlot.plotLayout()->addElement(i, 0, ar);
    }
    /*
    layout.addWidget(customPLot);
    plotWidget.setLayout(layout);
    */
    ui->plotArea_SA->setWidget(customPlot);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and the UI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1269</width>
    <height>454</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QScrollArea" name="plotArea_SA">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>169</x>
      <y>9</y>
      <width>1091</width>
      <height>381</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="widgetResizable">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>1089</width>
       <height>379</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QScrollArea" name="searchTable_SA">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>161</width>
      <height>151</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="widgetResizable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>159</width>
       <height>149</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QScrollArea" name="displayTable_SA">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>161</width>
      <height>221</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="widgetResizable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_3">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>159</width>
       <height>219</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1269</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setWidget()` function requires as a parameter the pointer of an object that inherits from `QWidget`. I recommend you create a pointer.

You must change to:

```
QCustomPlot *customPlot = new QCustomPlot;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    customPlot->plotLayout()->insertRow(i);
    QCPAxisRect *ar = new QCPAxisRect(customPlot);
    customPlot->plotLayout()->addElement(i, 0, ar);
}
ui->plotArea_SA->setWidget(customPlot);
```

Comment: Thank you for getting me started.

Comment: Is there a way to resize the axis to fit the qscrollarea in term of width and height?

Comment: You could use: `ar->setMinimumSize({}, {});` and place the size you want, the size of `QScrollArea` you can get it with: `ui->plotArea_SA->width();`, `ui->plotArea_SA->height();` and `ui->plotArea_SA->size();`